# Simple and 2-regular graph with exactly n vertices

Tags: graph-theory

How do i approach this problem:

For which natural numbers $n$ there exists a simple, 2-regular graph with exactly $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** I believe that a simple, 2-regular graph with exactly n vertices is called an n-cycle.

Comment: Thank you!. How about simple, 3-regular graph with exactly n vertices?

Comment: @jenn3 That's a separate question, but not hard either.

Comment: would this work for every n? how do i show that

Comment: The logic will work for every single $n$. For example, it suffices to consider: is there a 0-cylce? How about a 1-cycle? How about a 2-cycle?

Comment: Thanks again. For simple, 3-regular graph is basically called a cubic graph right? which exist for n >= 4 and even.

Comment: Yes. You can deal with the $k-$regular case easily, according to when $k$ is even (then $n \geq k+1$) of when $k$ is odd (then $n \geq k+1$ and even).